# Creation of a detached signature in CMS using SHA-512 for the hash

Tags: c++, cryptography, digital-signature, cryptoapi, asn.1

I have content and CMS with a detached signature (key algorithm - SHA-256) and
I add one more signature to the CMS with key algorithm SHA-512. But when adding with CryptoApi, the function `CryptMsgControl(hMsg, 0, CMSG_CTRL_ADD_SIGNER, &SignerEncodeInfo)` returns `CRYPT_E_UNKNOWN_ALGO`.

The reason for this is that in the CMS not exist SHA-512 in the [digestAlgoritm:
ASN.1 structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6tLD.png)

If I add the SHA-512 with ASN.1 editor, the signer info will be added: [ASN.1 after insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGgdY.png)

Is it possible to add this block or the SignerInfo using the CryptoApi directly or is it only possible by means of editing ASN.1?

Comment: Note that your question will not receive as much attention as it could because you haven't specified the language using a language tag. On StackOverflow, always specifies a language tag unless you ask one of the few on-topic questions that are [tag:language-agnostic].

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to do this.

I created a template containing algorithms but not containing signer info and certificate. It can be done using asn1 editor or CryptoApi (using the `CryptMsgOpenToDecode` and `CryptMsgControl(..., CMSG_CTRL_DEL_SIGNER, ...)`)
Then need to transfer the signer info and certificates from the current signature to the template created above

```
PCMSG_CMS_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo;
DWORD cbSignerInfo;
CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg2, CMSG_CMS_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM, 0, NULL, &cbSignerInfo);
pSignerInfo = (PCMSG_CMS_SIGNER_INFO)LocalAlloc(LPTR, cbSignerInfo);
CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg2, CMSG_CMS_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM, 0, (PVOID)pSignerInfo, &cbSignerInfo);

CryptMsgControl(hMsg, 0, CMSG_CTRL_ADD_CMS_SIGNER_INFO, pSignerInfo);

DWORD cbCertInfo;
CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg2, CMSG_CERT_PARAM, 0, NULL, &cbCertInfo);
std::vector<BYTE> pCertInfo(cbCertInfo);
CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg2, CMSG_CERT_PARAM, 0, &pCertInfo[0], &cbCertInfo);

CRYPT_INTEGER_BLOB certBlob;
memset(&certBlob, 0, sizeof(CRYPT_INTEGER_BLOB));
certBlob.cbData = cbCertInfo;
certBlob.pbData = &pCertInfo[0];
CryptMsgControl(hMsg, 0, CMSG_CTRL_ADD_CERT, &certBlob);
```

After that, you can add a new signature.

Comment: Still, do not use this solution. The function with the `CMSG_CTRL_ADD_CMS_SIGNER_INFO` parameter can change the order of the signed attributes.